# How can I add language aliases to highlightjs?

Tags: arrays, associative-array, highlightjs

According to the [highlightjs docs](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#configure-options) you can pass a an array of languages to the `configure` object. The example in the documentation as shown below does not give an example of how to use the `languages` parameter.

```
hljs.configure({
  tabReplace: '    ', // 4 spaces
  classPrefix: ''     // don't append class prefix
                      // … other options aren't changed
})
hljs.initHighlighting();
```

Exporting source code from emacs uses the class `src-language` rather than just `language` and highlightjs autodetects wrongly sometimes.

So it recognizes `src-emacs-lisp` as `scheme` rather than `elisp` or just `lisp`. So for the list of aliases, how do I configure the `languages` array of the object? Are there any working examples?

Answer (score 0):

As an example if a highlightjs installation supports a shell like `bash` but not `zsh` and `fish` and as the user you think the bash configuration will work with `zsh` and `fish` you can configut thus:

```js
var bash = hljs.requireLanguage("bash").rawDefinition();
bash.aliases.concat(["zsh","fish","etc"])
// push the new bash back overtop of the old one
hljs.registerLanguage("bash", bash)
```

In relation to the question's example where org-mode exports `lisp` code as `src-emacs-lisp` and `lisp` is configured in highlightjs the code would be

```js
var lispHighlight = hljs.requireLanguage("lisp").rawDefinition();
lispHighlight.aliases.concat(["src-emacs-lisp"])
hljs.registerLanguage("lisp", lispHighlight)
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing but for kts/kotlin:
```const kotlin = hljs.getLanguage("kotlin");
const kotlinDef = hljs.getLanguage("kotlin").rawDefinition();
kotlinDef.aliases.concat["kt", "kts", "kotlin"];
hljs.registerLanguage(kotlin.name, kotlinDef);
```
I get `Language definition for 'Kotlin' could not be registered.` error on htljs 10.5.0